# Do I need a useEffect for backend request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the below error when trying to send a request from frontend to backend:

```
App.js:22 GET http://localhost:3000/abc/id/1265 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)
VM531:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at handleSubmit (App.js:23:1)
```

```
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const resp = await fetch(`/abc/${searchType}/${search}`);
    const json = await resp.json();

    if (json.success) {
      return setData(json.thing);
    } else if (json.error) {
      return setData(null);
    }
  };
```

Comment: It means that your server is not sending a valid json

Comment: *Do I need a useEffect for backend request?* - no

Answer (score -1):

The error is due to the "return statement" in handleSubmit, remove the "return" keyword and only write setData(json.thing) or setData(null).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. Sadly removing the return key word didn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you use try-catch syntax? It should work. I am sorry I am also not an expert of the language.